# MS Access Global Variable

Tags: ms-access, variables, global

I have a single global variable that checks for when a form is filled out that I can't get to work.  I tried just setting it in the module, but it doesn't seem to work.  I've over complicated it by putting this in the Module..

```
    Option Compare Database

Public ChangeFlag As Boolean

Public Function SetFlagTrue()
ChangeFlag = True
End Function

Public Function SetFlagFalse()
ChangeFlag = False
End Function

Public Function GetFlag() As Boolean
GetFlag = ChangeFlag
End Function
```

I thought since it wasn't working passing the value back and forth, I could call a function to change it and then call the GetFlag.  Still doesn't work.

I tried using `Call SetFlagTrue` but I get an error, and when I try to change the value.  Here's where I refer to GetFlag function, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
If (GetFlag = True) Then
MsgBox ("Data already entered for today, use Edit button")
End If

If (GetFlag = False) Then...
```

I don't think they work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Property instead of Functions

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private DataEntered As Boolean

Public Property Get FormHasData() As Boolean
  FormHasData = DataEntered
End Property

Public Property Let FormHasData(ByVal HasData As Boolean)
  DataEntered = HasData
End Property

Private Sub TestFormHasData
  FormHasData = True
  Debug.Print FormHasData
  FormHasData = False
  Debug.Print FormHasData
End Sub
```

By setting`DataEnterd`to private, it can only be accessed by its Getter/Letter. A property has the advantage of only one identifier for this task. You can now make the Letter private, to prevent changes from outside the module, or make the Getter private to prevent access to it from outside.

That's the diff to your code, where`ChangeFlag`could be accessed from everywhere.